# Woocommerce - Add border image to products

Tags: css, woocommerce, styles, border-image

I'm trying to add a border-image around each product, I've designed the image in illustrator but can't get it to show. The src etc is correct.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products 
li.product {
    border-image-slice: 50 56 27 58;
    border-image-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source:url(bkg-img.png);
}
```

the image is as so 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also specify `border-style` and `border-width` (`border-image` only replaces `border-color` and without `width` and `style`, it defaults to `0`, `none`, respectively):

```css
img {
  border: 20px solid;
  border-image-slice: 50 56 27 58;
  border-image-width: 20px;
  border-image-outset: 0;
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
  border-image-source: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAphp.png');
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/135">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x135">
```

Comment: Brilliant, that was it. Thanks.